# How to limit number of connections from Chromium to SOCKS5 proxy server?

Tags: chromium, socks, dante

I am using Chromium to scrape data and during high scale Chromium is creating a large number of tcp connections to the SOCKS5 proxy(Dante). According to my observations, for just two tabs there were 15 connections to the proxy and the number of connections went up to 25 when I opened four tabs. I am trying to figure out if there's a way to limit these connections either at Chromium or at Dante.

Answer (score 2):

Dante supports limiting the number of sessions (connections) from a given client using it's session module syntax.  E.g., adding the below to the appropriate rules in your sockd.conf would limit the number of sessions per client to 10:

```
#per-ip limit
session.state.key: from
session.state.max: 10
```

More information is available on the Dante website: https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.4.x/config/session.html